# Entity Framework Change Schema Name Per Connection

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I am developing an application that will segregate client data into different schemas in MS SQL Server 2008.  The table structure is the same for each schema.  Entity Framework 4.1 will be used to access the data, using a different connection string per client.  The user in the connection string is set up to use a particular schema in the database and that is not an issue.

The issue that I am having is that the schema name in the queries is hardcoded in the EDMX.  if I remove the schema name from each entity in the .edmx then .NET uses the EntityContainer name instead. How can a go about changing this schema name per connection?
I am using a generic DbContext to make my connections with a connection string being provided per request.

I've tried Brandon Haynes [EF ModelAdapter](http://efmodeladapter.codeplex.com/) on codeplex but that does not seem to work against the latest version of EF.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Solving this with EDMX + `DbContext` will be probably hard because the only way is to have separate SSDL for every schema. SSDL is part of your EDMX file and it is the part where all tables are defined including the name of their schema. You can change SSDL at runtime (it is just XML by default stored as resource of your assembly) but you will have to manually create `MetadataWorkspace` for every schema, use it to create `EntityConnection` and pass connection to context constructor.

EF ModelAdapter is based on `ObjectContext` so you will have to use ObjectContext API (.NET 4.0) instead of DbContext API if you want to use it.

If you move to code mapping (no EDMX but fluent API used to describe mapping) it will be possible to achieve it because you will be able to parametrize your single mapping set and use multiple `DbModel` instances (one per schema).